# Control on SQL join condition when there are more than one matching row

Tags: sql, hive

I have a join with more than one matching row. How can I have more control over the join? In particular, as shown in the example, when there is more than one matching row, I don't want to obtain any result and maintain my input.

In the picture, I am showing the desired result. The row with the green color is correctly obtained because of directing matching and the row with the red color is also correctly not obtained, because there are more than one matching.

```
Select t2.id, t1.Insurance_num, t1Name, t1.Surname
From Table_1 t1
left join Table_2 t2
on t1.Insurance_num=t2.Insurance_num
```

[image]

I am using [Hive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hive), but I guess the answer to this question should be a generic one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hive - does it have the concept of Select Distinct ?

Comment: yes, but it cannot be used with groupby

Comment: I'm not familiar with hive either. It is simple with SQL where you can use a subquery and see whether the matching rows' minimum ID equals the maximum ID, or use group by with a having clause and join the result, or join all rows, then count IDs on-the-fly and remove those with a count greater than one, or use an exists clause to see whether another row matches beside the found one... I don't now what's possible in hive, though.

Comment: @Woeitg- there was no group by in your code and group by essentially removes the need for distinct.
As to your comment on clarity - you appear to want N.D. in the results but that is the id from table 1 not table 2. Perhaps if you explained what you are trying to achieve it would be clearer

Comment: Please review *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)* and *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and ***[do the needful](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72277529/edit)***. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this...  I am not sure if it is exactly what you need.

If the coalesce with left-join would be null if no matching Insurance_Num, thus returning 0, *or*, there *is* a matching insurance_num, but the count is *other* than 1, it gets the *ELSE* condition of the CASE query.

Only if there *is* a match in the pre-query, *and* there is one record for that insurance_num does it get the ID from that pre-aggregation query.

```
select
      case when coalesce( PreSum.NumEntries, 0 ) = 1
           then cast( PreSum.LowID as varchar )
           else 'N.D' end as IDorNot,
      t1.Insurance_num,
      t1.Name,
      t1.Surname
   from
      table_1 t1
         LEFT JOIN
         ( select
                 t2.Insurance_Num,
                 min( t2.id ) as LowID,
                 count(*) as NumEntries
              from
                 Table_2 t2
              group by
                 t2.Insurance_Num ) PreSum
            on t1.insurance_Num = PreSum.Insurance_Num
```